# Kubernetes + Helm - only restart pods if new version/change

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Whenever I run my basic deploy command, everything is redeployed in my environment. Is there any way to tell Helm to only apply things if there were changes made or is this just the way it works?

I'm running:

```sh
helm upgrade --atomic MyInstall . -f CustomEnvironmentData.yaml
```

I didn't see anything in the [Helm Upgrade documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/) that seemed to indicate this capability.

I don't want to bounce my whole evironment unless I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `helm diff upgrade`

https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff

```
$ helm diff upgrade - h
Show a diff explaining what a helm upgrade would change.

    This fetches the currently deployed version of a release
    and compares it to a chart plus values.
    This can be used visualize what changes a helm upgrade will
perform.

    Usage:
diff upgrade[flags] [RELEASE] [CHART]

Examples:
helm diff upgrade my-release stable / postgresql--values values.yaml

Flags:
-h, --help                   help for upgrade
    --detailed - exitcode      return a non - zero exit code when there are changes
--post - renderer string the path to an executable to be used for post rendering. If it exists in $PATH, the binary will be used, otherwise it will try to look for the executable at the given path
--reset - values           reset the values to the ones built into the chart and merge in any new values
    --reuse - values           reuse the last release's values and merge in any new values
    --set stringArray        set values on the command line(can specify multiple or separate values with commas: key1 = val1, key2 = val2)
--suppress stringArray   allows suppression of the values listed in the diff output
    - q, --suppress - secrets       suppress secrets in the output
    - f, --values valueFiles      specify values in a YAML file(can specify multiple)(default[])
    --version string         specify the exact chart version to use.If this is not specified, the latest version is used

    Global Flags:
--no - color   remove colors from the output
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but this helps a lot.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to tell Helm to do this, but also no need.  If you submit an object to the Kubernetes API server that exactly matches something that's already there, generally nothing will happen.

For example, say you have a Deployment object that specifies `image: my/image:{{ .Values.tag }}` and `replicas: 3`.  You submit this once with `tag: 20200904.01`.  Now you run the `helm upgrade` command you show, with that `tag` value unchanged in the `CustomEnvironmentData.yaml` file.  This will in fact trigger the deployment controller inside Kubernetes.  That sees that it wants 3 pods to exist with the image `my/image:20200904.01`.  Those 3 pods already exist, so it does nothing.

(This is essentially the same as the "don't use the `latest` tag" advice: if you try to set `image: my/image:latest`, and redeploy your Deployment with this tag, since the Deployment spec is unchanged Kubernetes won't do anything, even if the version of the image in the registry has changed.)